# PHP caching dynamically constructed files

Tags: php, caching

I am currently working on a small personal framework for web applications, based on the MVC pattern. In this framework some pages and templates are dynamically constructed from multiple files. However, especially these templates won't change often, so I want to create some form of caching. Ideally I only want to update the cached files when the original source files are changed, and I want to update the cached files on the first request after one of the source files is changed. But since 1 cache file is constructed from multiple source files, I need some way to know which source files belongs to a cache file, so I know which files I need to check for updates.

I came up with the idea to either use a table in a database or a separate file which saves that information. However, this requires some extra overhead on each page request, since I'll have to read one more file or I'll have to do some database IO. Are there any other techniques I can use to have as little overhead as possible?

ps. Caching isn't really needed since I'll only use it for a few small websites on a server which is far too powerful for these websites. However, I think it's a good practice for me to become more used to caching techniques.

Comment: Only start with caching if you really need it. Otherwise it can not be specifically said what needs caching exactly and what not.

Comment: Write a function to "recompile" your dynamically created files and save the output to an `.html` file or something, and then run that script when you update one of the files.

Comment: @Hakre - But don't you think it's a good idea to become more comfortable with catching before you really need it? I think it's better for me to practice these kind of things on a small scale environment in which I can't really mess up that much than that I try new things in critical environments where errors can't be permitted.

Comment: @JaredFarrish - That might be a good idea! Perhaps I can create a script which is automatically called when I update certain files using ftp.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look into PHP APC, you can create SHA1 hashes for your templates and store them in the cache with long expiration times. You can create flags in the cache when things change, and retrieve the documents from the cache vs the file system.